# nginx rtmp-module can't execute ffmpeg

Tags: bash, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am having an issue with nginx-rtmp-module exec ffmpeg command. i have followed the example on 
www.github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module

```
/home/junaid/bin/ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video1 -c:v libx264 -an -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/myapp/mystream
```

the command is working fine in terminal

Config file:

```
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935;
    ping 30s;
    notify_method get;

    application myapp {
    live on;
    allow play all;
    exec_static /home/junaid/bin/ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video1 -c:v libx264 -an -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/myapp/mystream;      
 }
}
```

Error log:
http://www.codepad.org/enD4wlZ9

I have tried:

- nginx running as root (have permission to execute ffmpeg)
- using ip instead of localhost
- using complete path to ffmpeg
- executing bash file (having ffmpeg and echo commands: echo commands execute just fine) from nginx

please help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it. the problem was permission error to /dev/video0 
just changed /dev/video0 to rtsp address of camera

Answer (score 0):

exec commands need to have the program in PATH envs, so just install ffmpeg, or add

Answer (score 0):

Please check nginx status first:

```
systemctl status nginx
```

Make sure you command ffmpeg is running in nginx process.
If ffmpeg process is running and no thing happen. Please check permission at /dev/video0